# Passing Ruby array elements to a method

Tags: arrays, ruby, chef-infra

I'm not a programmer, but I find myself writing some simple ruby and aren't sure about a few things.

I have the following function

```
def resolve_name(ns_name)
  ip = Resolv.getaddress(ns_name)
  return ip
end
```

and the array

```
array = ['ns-1.me.com', 'ns-2.me.com']
```

What I want to do is to pass every element in the array to the function to be evaluated, and spit out to... something. Probably a variable. Once I have the resolved IPs I'll be passing them to an erb template. Not quite sure yet how to handle when there may be 1 to 4 possible results either.

What I want think I need to do is do an each.do and typecast to string into my function, but I haven't been able to figure out how to actually do that or phrase my problem properly for google to tell me.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion Doesn't quite have what I'm looking for.

```
irb(main):010:0> resolved = resolve_name(array)
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into String
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for ruby's [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html), which arrays implement. What you're looking for is the `map` method, which takes each element of an enumerable (i.e. an array) and passes it to a block, returning a new array with the results of the blocks. Like this:

```
array.map{|element| resolve_name(element) }
```

As an aside, in your method, you do not need to use a local variable if all you're doing with it is returning its value; and the return statement is optional - ruby methods always return the result of the last executed statement. So your method could be shortened to this:

```
def resolve_name(ns_name)
  Resolv.getaddress(ns_name)
end
```

and then you really all it's doing is wrapping a method call in another. So ultimately, you can just do this (with `array` renamed to `ns_names` to make it self-explanatory):

```
ns_names = ['ns-1.me.com', 'ns-2.me.com']
ip_addresses = ns_names.map{|name| Resolv.getaddress(name) }
```

Now `ip_addresses` is an array of IP addresses that you can use in your template.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass an array you could do:

```
def resolve_name(ns_name)
  res = []
  ns_name.each do |n|
    res << {name: n, ip:  Resolv.getaddress(name) } 
  end   
  res
end
```

And get an array of hashes so you know which address has which ip